# How to use IF - ELSE function in URL Button

Tags: custom-button, button, custom

I'm trying to create a custom clone button in the opportunity object.

```
    {!IF( ISPICKVAL( Opportunity.Type , "New Business") , "/{!Opportunity.Id}/e?
    clone=1&retURL=%2F{!Opportunity.Id}&00N90000008KH67=", "/{!Opportunity.Id}/e?
clone=1&retURL=%2F{!Opportunity.Id}")}
```

Is it possible to use functions within URL button

Comment: Yes, you can use the IF function in a detail page link. Can you please elaborate on what you mean by `But I'm not able to use If-Else functions in the formula field`?

Comment: Hey sorry, my bad i have updated the question. how to handle the above scenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use if condition inside an URL button in Salesforce. For example, see below button formula:-

```
{!IF( ISPICKVAL( Opportunity.Type , "New Business") , URLFOR('/'+Opportunity.Id+'/e? clone=1&retURL='+Opportunity.Id), URLFOR('/'+Opportunity.Id+'/e'))}
```

The key point is:-

1. Do not use curly braces inside if condition.
2. Use URLFOR function to generate URL inside if condition

[image]

Comment: Hey @sanket it worked very well but how to include custom fields

Comment: The same way you handle standard fields

Comment: Hey, @sanket when i click this button and save the record it actually updating the existing record instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the Sanket Kumar solution but it didn't work completely, Instead of cloning the opportunity, it is opening the edit window of the current opportunity.

But the URLFOR function is working as expected when i made some changes. I'm updating my answer maybe it would be helpful for others

```
{!IF( ISPICKVAL( Opportunity.Type , "New Business") && 
NOT( ISPICKVAL( Opportunity.StageName , 'Closed Won')),
URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.Clone,Opportunity.Id,['retURL'=Opportunity.Id,'00N2s000000uhbh'=1,
'00N6F00000EYw00'=0],true),
URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.Clone,Opportunity.Id,['retURL'=Opportunity.Id,'00N2s000000uhbh'=0,
'00N6F00000EYw00'=0],true))}
```